# How to Split <ul>'s every different variable

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I want to split `<ul>` every different `variable_name`

I tried inserting ul inside the if statement but it wont work. Is it possible to put ul without putting it outside the if statement?

Let's say my `variable_name = [dog,dog,dog,cat,cat,mouse,mouse,mouse,mouse];`

and the output i want is:

```html
<ul>
  <li> dog </li>
  <li> dog </li>
  <li> dog </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li> cat </li>
  <li> cat </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li> mouse </li>
  <li> mouse </li>
  <li> mouse </li>
  <li> mouse </li>


Code:
<% for(var j=0;j<array4.length;j++)  { %>
<%  if(array4[j].input_type == "radio") { %>

<li class="list-group-item radio-choice" id="chk_<%=array4[j].variable_name%>" value=""><%=array4[j].answer_text%> </li>

<%} }%>
```

Comment: Yes i did that, but im having a hard time on logic for <ul>

Answer (score 1):

In Node you can do it like this (directly in template, e.g. eJS):

```
<%

var variable_name = ['dog','dog','dog','cat','cat','mouse','mouse','mouse','mouse'];
var uls = [];
variable_name.forEach(function(item) {
    uls[item] = uls[item] ? ++uls[item] : 1;
});
for(var key in uls) {
    %><ul><%
    for (var i=0; i<uls[key]; i++) {
        %><li><%= key %></li><%
    }
    %></ul><%
}

%>
```

You can test this with console logs in Javascript like this:

```
var variable_name = ['dog','dog','dog','cat','cat','mouse','mouse','mouse','mouse'];
var uls = [];
variable_name.forEach(function(item) {
    uls[item] = uls[item] ? ++uls[item] : 1;
});
for(var key in uls) {
    console.log('<ul>');
    for (var i=0; i<uls[key]; i++) {
        console.log('<li>'+key+'</li>');
    }
    console.log('</ul>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @JohnCarloVelasquez: Can you please accept this as the correct answer if it worked for you.